# How to remember current tab on Liferay

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I'm trying to remember current tab on JSP page. I'm working on Liferay portal and using liferay-ui:tabs.
This is mu JSP implementation of tabs

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/util" prefix="liferay-util" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<a href='<portlet:renderURL portletMode="view"/>'><liferay-ui:message
    key="label.backToList" /></a>

<liferay-ui:tabs names="tab1,tab2" refresh="false"  param="tabs1"    tabsValues="tab1,tab2" >
   <liferay-ui:section>
       <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/view1.jsp"/>
       <portlet:param name="tabs1" value="tab1" /> 
   </liferay-ui:section>
   <liferay-ui:section>
       <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/view2.jsp"/>
       <portlet:param name="tabs1" value="tab2" /> 
   </liferay-ui:section>
```

In my controller method I try to get current tab

```
@RenderMapping(params = "myaction=showTabs")
public String showRTIDetails(Model model, RenderRequest request) {

    String tabs1 = request.getParameter("tabs1");
    if(tabs1 == null || tabs1.isEmpty()){
        tabs1="tab2";
    }
    PortletURL tabUrl= response.createRenderURL();
    tabUrl.setParameter("tabs1", tabs1);
    return "view";

}
```

but result is that I when I am on tab1 and refresh page in my controller get 'tab2'as result of

```
request.getParameter("tabs1");
```

How to remember current tab so when I refresh page I stay on the same tab?

Comment: I think it's because you have used `refresh="false"`. When you click on tab1 there is no request to server (content of both tabs is loaded on first request) and requestbody is not changing (query parameter tabs1 is not reloaded), so after refresh page loaded tab is tab2.

Comment: It works now, thank you.